# Object and Arrays - Getting values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am unable to return the values of an objects in an array.

The  value of the object in the array looks like this:

[image]

I'm able to pull values easily if I specify the object ID, but I'm trying to get the list of objects so I know the IDs prior to getting values.

listproductsdata4dtgeet is the array of objects

I want to be able to simply get the IDs in a list or array.

**10110DT01VAR003981**

**10212DT01VAR004051**

**etc...**

Once I have that list I can easily get the values by using

**listproductsdata4dtgeet["10110DT01VAR003981"].name
listproductsdata4dtgeet["10110DT01VAR003981"].category**

**etc...**

Comment: None of the code you posted makes any sense. It's not correct syntax. Where's the code you used to create these arrays and objects?

Comment: You are storing objects into an array, each object has `id`, `name` and `category`?

Comment: I posted a screenshot instead of a copy/paste.

Comment: Ok, I see the data structure now. Say you've got a list of ids, you still wouldn't able to get the object by `listproductsdata4dtgeet["10110DT01VAR003981"].name`, you need the array index too to access such as `listproductsdata4dtgeet[arrayIndex]["10110DT01VAR003981"].name`. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Actually once I have the IDs it's easy to call the parameters.

listproductsdata4dtgeet["10110DT01VAR003981"].name;
"Bai Hao Yin Zhen"

Answer (score 3):

To get the ids you need to get the keys :

```
var ids = Object.keys(listproductsdata4dtgeet);
```

or since it appears to be a single item array :

```
var ids = Object.keys(listproductsdata4dtgeet[0]);
```

Comment: listproductsdata4dtgeet is an array though

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, because what you posted doesn't make too much sense. Is listproductsdata4dtgeet an array? Try:

```
listproductsdata4dtgeet[0]["<product id>"].name
```